# Share address book contact with share extension

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create share extension to share a contact to my app.

Is it possible? i can't see any documentation.
If you want to share contact the only share options now is sms email and WhatsApp and i want to add my app too.

Thank you.

Comment: You can get contacts/contact from your phonebook using ABAddressBook & import to your app . Read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/index.html

Comment: I don't want to manually read phone book. I want from address book to share a contact to my app

Comment: Do you want to magically read the phonebook then? Be more clear in your specifications then and tell us what exactly are you trying to do. I don't know what do you mean by "I don't want to manually read phonebook"

Comment: When you open a contact you have an option to share the contact to email sms act . so i want to add there my app

Comment: Have you seen this then? http://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-8-app-extensions

Comment: I know i need to create Share Extension, but my question is how to set it to recieve contact. I've done before Share Extension with photos but i don't know how to share contact

Comment: I know you need to add a value to info.plist with supported types, but the type you need to add to support share contacts?